# Flying from France to the UK with only ID card

Tags: air-travel, passports

Is it possible for me to fly from France to the UK with just an ID card ?
If this is possible which airlines will allow you to fly with just an ID card ?

Comment: Do you mean your official EU ID card, which will be accepted instead of a passport for most journeys within Europe? If so, yes. But if you mean 'any ID like a driving license' not without a lot of trouble. This is a duplicate question, it has been asked before.

Comment: Is there such a thing as an "EU ID card"?

Comment: It is the national ID card which follows the EU standard and is often called EU ID card. The UK among others does not have it, France has it.

Comment: What is your nationality?

Comment: @blackbird57 While I agree that there are similar issues implicated in the proposed duplicate, the particulars of the question are somewhat different.

Comment: @Willeke While there are rules about driving licenses, passports and residence permits, I don't think there is actually an EU standard about this, ID cards come in different shapes. But EU countries have to recognize them nonetheless.

Comment: @Relaxed The closest is as far as I know [this Council resolution](http://europa.eu/rapid/press-release_PRES-06-341_en.htm?locale=en) regarding security features.

Answer (score 4):

If you are from a country whose citizens can enter the UK with a national ID card in lieu of a passport, then yes, you can fly to the UK with your national ID card and no passport.  Those countries are the countries of the EU and the EEA, plus Switzerland.  https://www.gov.uk/uk-border-control/before-you-leave-for-the-uk.

Note that the "ID card" here is a *national ID card* that must indicate your nationality.  A driver's license or other form of ID does not meet the requirement.

If you are flying to the UK with a national ID card, all airlines will allow you to board with that ID card.

If you are a national of another country, you cannot enter the UK without a passport.  (Depending on your nationality and the purpose of your trip, you may also require a visa.)