# Travelling from Denmark to UK and back with id card

Tags: uk, denmark, identity-cards

I hold Lithuania citizenship and currently live in Denmark. Is it possible to travel to UK from Denmark and back using only the identity card?

According to [gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/uk-border-control/before-you-leave-for-the-uk)

> You can enter the UK with either a valid passport or a national identity card issued by a EEA country. It must be valid for the whole of your stay.

I am fully aware that this question was asked a number of times, for example [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71864/flying-from-france-to-the-uk-with-only-id-card). However, since "Brexit" situation might have changed. Moreover, recently while travelling from Copenhagen airport to Dublin I was asked to prove validity of my identity card using additional document (e.g. driving license).

Comment: `since "Brexit" situation might have changed` Where did you read this or got this information from ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of June 2017, the Brexit has not happened **yet** and negotiations are still ongoing.

Unless all 28 current members agree to a different date (part of a *soft Brexit*), the UK is an EU member until 30 March 2019 (*hard Brexit*).